# What exactly is an RTK GNSS receiver?

Tags: gps, accuracy, base-station

I have seen many GNSS/INS sensors come with "RTK GNSS receivers" which enable you to achieve RTK. I have been looking at the sensor I have got which claims to be RTK capable, the user manual says it only needs GNSS antenna to be set in the rover mode, [InertialSense](http://docs.inertialsense.com/user-manual/App_Usage/rtk/).

Hence my question is: how is RTK GNSS receiver different from GNSS receiver? How can my sensor achieve RTK without an RTK GNSS receiver?

Comment: This is a good source: https://www.novatel.com/an-introduction-to-gnss/chapter-5-resolving-errors/real-time-kinematic-rtk/ coded based non RTK vs carrier-based ranging RTK

Comment: @Mapperz, I had already read that, I still don't understand how a non RTK receiver can support RTK.. Or what RTK receiver is in general.

Comment: You don't need only an antenna, you also need a "base station" which will help remove errors in the rover's location.

Comment: @mkennedy, that part I understand, my main question is how is an "RTK GNSS receiver" different from a "GNSS receiver"? My sensor with an only "GNSS receiver" is capable of RTK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GNSS receiver isn't necessarily capable of receiving RTK corrections. For example, a standard off-the-shelf Garmin unit for recreational acitivities will generally only use SBAS (WAAS, EGNOS, etc.) for differential corrections and provide a one to a few meters of accuracy.

The higher-end GNSS receiver used for survey, construction, GIS and other applications that require high-accuracy results, have a GNSS board that offers RTK processing. This RTK correction will usually come from a local base station via a UHF or spread spectrum radio or internet-based corrections from a GNSS network.

Take a look at data sheets from some of the survey or GIS devices like the Leica GS18t, GS16, GG04 plus. These will outline RTK accuracy capabilities. These GNSS receivers contain the GNSS board as well as the GNSS antenna, so it is an complete solution. They are also multi-frequency, so obtaining high-accuracy results with longer baselines is easier compared to single frequency GNSS receivers.

From the looks of your device it is only the GNSS unit. You would need to have a GNSS antenna attached in order to receive signal. This antenna should be mounted in a way it has an good view to the sky for optimal reception.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I was able to set up RTK with it through TCP the other day and had "RTK: Fix" status. This is what confuses me, it looks like a normal GNSS unit but is capable of RTK, how?

Comment: It could be that they have the RTK processing built-into their GNSS receiver. It would be a question for the manufacturer of the receiver.